# the Construction of and passing of parameters of a method that searches a 2-d array filled with random numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, methods, parameters

I am having problems with the last method of my program.  I can't seem to figure out the right way to pass the parameters or maybe perhaps the way I have the method coded is wwrong.  Please help!  The stipulations of the method is below:

The `SearchArray()` method will return a bool to indicate if the number searched for was found or not. Its parameter is supposed to have:  An integer that is the number to be searched for, a two-dimensional array to search, an out reference integer parameter that will represent the row index and an out reference integer parameter that will represent the column index
This method will use the first parameter and the two-dimensional array and will search the array for the number chosen by the `GetNumber()` method. I must Initialize the row and column parameters to -1. As the program goes through the array, if the number is found, assign the row and column parameters to the row and column index numbers where it is found and stop searching the array right away. The method is supposed to return a Boolean value to indicate whether or not the number was found.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated I have been on here for awhile trying to get this figured out completely right now if I run it it gets to the point where it asks for a number then runs into an error stating the index is outside the boundaries.   Here is my code so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int [,] randomNumArray = new int[3, 5];

        FillArray(randomNumArray);
        PrintArray(randomNumArray);
        SumRows(randomNumArray);
        SumCols(randomNumArray);
        SumArray(randomNumArray);
        int rows, cols;
        int search = GetNumber();

        SearchArray(search, randomNumArray, out rows, out cols);


    }

    public static void FillArray(int[,] randomNumbersArray)
    {
        Random num = new Random();
        for (int r = 0; r < randomNumbersArray.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < randomNumbersArray.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                randomNumbersArray[r, c] = num.Next(15, 97);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void PrintArray(int[,] randomPrintArray)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < randomPrintArray.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < randomPrintArray.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0,3:F0}", randomPrintArray[r, c]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    public static void SumRows(int[,] sumOfRowsArray)
    {
        int rowSum;
        for (int r = 0; r < sumOfRowsArray.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            rowSum = 0;
            for (int c = 0; c < sumOfRowsArray.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                rowSum += sumOfRowsArray[r, c];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The total sum for row "+ (r + 1) + " is:  " + rowSum + ".");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    public static void SumCols(int[,] sumOfColsArray)
    {
        int colsSum;
        for (int c = 0; c < sumOfColsArray.GetLength(1); c++)
        {
            colsSum = 0;
            for (int r = 0; r < sumOfColsArray.GetLength(0); r++)
            {
                colsSum += sumOfColsArray[r, c];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The total sum for column " + (c + 1) + " is:  " + colsSum + ".");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    public static void SumArray(int[,] sumOfAllArray)
    {
        int sumOfAll = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < sumOfAllArray.GetLength(0); r++)
        {

            for (int c = 0; c < sumOfAllArray.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                sumOfAll += sumOfAllArray[r, c];
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Total for sum of the Array is:  "  + sumOfAll + "\n");
    }

    public static int GetNumber()
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter a number between 15 and 96:  ");
        int chosenNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (chosenNumber > 96 || chosenNumber < 15)
        {
            Console.Write("Number not between 15 and 96.  Try again:  ");
            chosenNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        return chosenNumber;
    }


    public static bool SearchArray(int soughtOutNum, int [,] searchableArray, out int rowIndex, out int colsIndex)
    {
        rowIndex = -1;
        colsIndex = -1;

        for (int c = 0; c < searchableArray.GetLength(0); c++)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < searchableArray.GetLength(1); r++)
            {
                if (searchableArray[r, c] == soughtOutNum)
                {
                    rowIndex = r;
                    colsIndex = c;
                    return true;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What is not working with your current code?

Comment: When I run the program  it prompts me to choose a number between 15- 96 when I enter anything it crashes and give me an error saying "Index was outside the boundary of array.

Comment: I also don't know if what I have coded is okay by the stipulations such has having `int search = getNumber()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ for your SearchArray.

```
public static bool SearchArray(int soughtOutNum, int [,] searchableArray, out int rowIndex, out int colsIndex)
{
    if(searchableArray.Any(x => soughtOutNum))
    {
        colsIndex = searchableArray.FirstOrDefault(x => x == soughtOutNum).GetLength(0);
        rowIndex= searchableArray.FirstOrDefault(x => x == soughtOutNum).GetLength(1);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }        
}
```

This returns your first hit's column and row.

Comment: I believe I am restricted to using `for` , `foreach` , `while` and `if` loops and statments